# Kinect 2.0 barcode scanning

Tags: kinect, barcode-scanner

I was wondering if there were any third party libraries that provide support for barcode scanning using Kinect 2.0 in C#.

I think the Kinect SDK doesn't provide any support for such a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZXing.Net supports Kinect.

https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net

You need the zxing.dll and the zxing.kinect.dll from the binaries package.
ZXing.Net is available as NuGet package but it doesn't include the zxing.kindect.dll.